# booting problem on Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, opensolaris

I am not able to connect to my server via network and plug console cable via A Lom port and keep getting this message and can't do anything. since I am not able to go ok> prompt. I am logged thorough terminal windows. I an't find a way to go ok> prompt.
   `Timeout waiting for ARP/RARP packet` 
any suggestion. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have a terminal connection in to the ALOM, so I assume your server is a V240 or similar. To get to the `ok` prompt from there:

1. Exit out of the console by typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> (that's the enter key, followed by hash, followed by dot). You should now be at the `sc>` prompt.
2. Send a break signal by typing `break -y`
3. Return to the console with `console -f`

As Iain says, the console messages indicate that the server is trying to boot off the network. You can use the `boot` command to manually boot off a disk or cdrom. You should also change the default boot device. At the `ok` prompt you can do this with the `printenv` and `setenv` commands, or alternatively you can boot into Solaris and do this with the `eeprom` command.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, this means that your system is trying to boot from the network but there is no boot server to boot from (or it is not configured correctly).

If you expect your system to boot from your network then check the configuration of your boot server. If you expect to boot from a disk/dvd then check that the disk/dvd is available.
Using the ALOM getto the OK prompt and try bootimg from the disk

```
ok boot disk
```

or

```
ok boot cdrom
```

Have a look [**here**](http://adminschoice.com/booting-problems-in-solaris) for other Solaris boot diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a PC to connect via the serial console, I believe if you hit Control-BREAK it'll stop the netboot attempts and return to the ok> prompt.